# Julian Date Distance Calculator (First Project)

Tags: python

I have watched a few youtube videos, and I am trying to learn a little bit more by doing. I had a blast trying to figure this out. I know it has issues such as not being able to go below 2001 and using an average for months. I'm not seeking to improve its capabilities, although i would certainly appreciate any ideas, seeking a review of the code and ways to improve. Thank you!

**The code works**

```
sd = input("Starting Julien Date (Enter as '00-000')")
ed = input("Ending Julian Date (Enter as '00-000')")

# This section gives you days from sd to ed
cy = int(ed[:2])
cd = int(ed[3:])

subyear = int(sd[:2])
yeardaycount = (cy - subyear) * 365

subdays = int(sd[3:])
daycount = cd - subdays

finalcount = yeardaycount + daycount

# This breaks the Finalcount into day, month, year.
y = finalcount / 365
y = int(y)
m = (finalcount - (y * 365)) / 30.4166666667
m = int(m)
d = finalcount - ((y * 365) + (m * 30.4166666667))
d = int(d)

print("From %s to %s, ~on average~, it has beeen %s days, %s months, and %s years." % (sd, ed, d, m, y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [`datetime` — Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) and [third-party package `dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as follows (given a script with hard-coded initial values):

```
sd = '03-023' # input("Starting Julien Date (Enter as 'yy-ddd')")
ed = '22-088' # input("Ending Julian Date (Enter as 'yy-ddd')")

# This section gives you days from sd to ed
cy = int(ed[:2])
cd = int(ed[3:])
subyear = int(sd[:2])
yeardaycount = (cy - subyear) * 365
subdays = int(sd[3:])
daycount = cd - subdays
finalcount = yeardaycount + daycount
# This breaks the Finalcount into day, month, year.
y = finalcount / 365
y = int(y)
m = (finalcount - (y * 365)) / 30.4166666667
m = int(m)
d = finalcount - ((y * 365) + (m * 30.4166666667))
d = int(d)

print("From %s to %s, ~on average~, it has beeen %s days, %s months, and %s years." % (sd, ed, d, m, y))

### using libraries:

from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

date_a = datetime.strptime( sd, "%y-%j")
date_b = datetime.strptime( ed, "%y-%j")

diff = relativedelta.relativedelta( date_b, date_a)

ms = diff.months
ys = diff.years
ds = diff.days

print("From %s to %s, ~   exactly~, it has beeen %s days, %s months, and %s years." % (sd, ed, ds, ms, ys))
```

**Output**: `.\CR\273990.py`

```
From 03-023 to 22-088, ~on average~, it has beeen 4 days, 2 months, and 19 years.
From 03-023 to 22-088, ~   exactly~, it has beeen 6 days, 2 months, and 19 years.
```